# How to add and remove value onclick event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've two tables one with objects and their values, other with options to the user click that change the another table values.

[Image of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BCDf.png)

If the user click one time, the values change correctly, however, if the user click again, the values won't change correctly.

For example:

```js
let teams = [
        {name: 'Roma', points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, loses: 0},
        {name: 'Atalanta', points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, loses: 0},
        {name: 'Milan', points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, loses: 0},
        {name: 'Fiorentina', points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, loses: 0},
    ]
let matches = [
        // Round 1.
        {homeName: teams[0].name, teamHome: 0, win: '', draw: '', awayTeamWin: '', teamAway: 1, awayName: teams[1].name},
        {homeName: teams[2].name, teamHome: 2, win: '', draw: '', awayTeamWin: '', teamAway: 3, awayName: teams[3].name},
        // Round 2.
        {homeName: teams[0].name, teamHome: 0, win: '', draw: '', awayTeamWin: '', teamAway: 2, awayName: teams[2].name},
        {homeName: teams[1].name, teamHome: 1, win: '', draw: '', awayTeamWin: '', teamAway: 3, awayName: teams[3].name},
        // Round 3.
        {homeName: teams[0].name, teamHome: 0, win: '', draw: '', awayTeamWin: '', teamAway: 3, awayName: teams[3].name},
        {homeName: teams[1].name, teamHome: 1, win: '', draw: '', awayTeamWin: '', teamAway: 2, awayName: teams[2].name},
    ]
```

```js
function matchWinnerTeamPoints(matchWinner) {
        matchWinner.points += 3;
        matchWinner.wins ++;
}
function matchLoserTeamPoints(matchLoser) {
        matchLoser.loses ++;
}
function matchDrawPoints(teamHome, teamAway) {
        teamHome.points ++;
        teamAway.points ++;
        teamHome.draws ++;
        teamAway.draws ++;
}
```

```js
function createMatchesTable(matchesTableBody, matches) {
        cleaner(matchesTableBody);
          let win = bodyRow.insertCell(-1);
          if (match.win === true) {
              win.className = 'bg-success';
          }
          win.onclick = (e) => {
              match.draw = '';
              match.awayTeamWin = '';
              match.win = !match.win;
              createMatchesTable(matchesTableBody, matches);
              matchWinnerTeamPoints(teams[match.teamHome]);
              matchLoserTeamPoints(teams[match.teamAway]);
              cleaner(createStandingTable(standingTableBody, teams));
          }
```

Once the user click on win cell the team get 3 points and 1 win, but if the user click again the team will receive more 3 points and 1, but I want to remove the 3 points and 1 win, however I don't know how.

Comment: If you want to toggle something, you need a flag to tell the function to do something or do the opposite. So pass a Boolean value (perhaps `match.win`?) to `matchWinnerTeamPoints` and, if it's true, add 3 to points and 1 to wins. If it's false, subtract 3 from points and 1 from wins. Or switch the true/false depending on what you want it to do; it's not clear what these values mean or what their values are before clicking.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer, I don't know how to use flag, i saw examples in other questions and I tried to implement on the code, on the first click worked, however when i click on the others cells don't add points 'cause the flag is false.

Answer (score 0):

so the same button does two different mutation, is there a pattern to it? best to have two buttons & functions, one for add, one for remove. but you can make it with one method by supplying an argument with either negative or positive values. depending on action

e.g

```
function matchWinnerTeamPoints(match Winner, p, w) {
        matchWinner.points += p;
        matchWinner.wins += w;
    

}
```